# how to make my nav bar responsive with logo on left side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying for a while to make my nav bar responsive but I am unable to. any help would be appreciated. I need the logo to sits next to on the left when the screen is 700px in width or less (media queries) and make a sandwich icon which opens up the menu. I know there are other questions like this but none of them meet the standards.

```css
.logo{
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
}

#logo1{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1000000;
       position: fixed;
}

header::after {
   content: '';
display: table;
    clear:both;
}

nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10%;
    
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0 ;
    list-style: none; 
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 28px;
    position: relative;
    
}

nav a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/jquery.scrollTo-2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <Div id="gg"><div id="header" class="container">
   <img src="logo1.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
       <!--<h1 id="logo1">SLAD </h1>-->
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li ><a href="#welcomesec" class="slide-section">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="slide-section">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="slide-section">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#clientssection" class="slide-section">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="slide-section">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div></Div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add this tag to your HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Add one tag for for each of the elements you wish to display

```
<div class="burguer"/>

<div class="logo/>
```

and display them or not depending on screen size

```
.burguer{
@media (min-width: 700) { display:none} // or change position...
}
.logo{
@media (max-width: 700) { display:none }
}
```

Comment: I understand i have to use these but how?